# String Concatenation not working in C (TDM-GCC-64)

Tags: c, gcc

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
  char fn[20], ln[20], fulln[20];
  int i, j, k;
  printf("Enter your first name: ");
  scanf("%s",fn);
  printf("Enter your last name: ");
  scanf("%s",ln);
  for(i=0,k=0;fn[i]!='\0'; i++, k++)
  {
    fulln[k] = fn[i];
  }
  k++;
  for(j=0;ln[j]!='\0';j++,k++)
  {
    fulln[k] = ln[j];
  }
  fulln[k] = '\0';
  printf("Your full name is %s",fulln);
  return 0;
}
```

Cannot understand what is wrong with it. It doesn't show the full name. I am using TDM-GCC-64(latest version)

Comment: Simple math: 20+ 20 != 40.

Comment: Also read about [`strcat()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat). The destination must have enough memory to hold the concatenated result, plus null-terminator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is basically doing a `strcpy` and `strcat` manually.

```
  for(i=0,k=0;fn[i]!='\0'; i++, k++)
  {
    fulln[k] = fn[i];
  }
  k++;
  for(j=0;ln[j]!='\0';j++,k++)
  {
    fulln[k] = ln[j];
  }
  fulln[k] = '\0';
```

There were problems with your code:

- You should initialise all the char buffer, like this:  `char fn[20] = "", ln[20] = "", fulln[41] = "";`
- Also, you should make sure `fulln` is big enough to contain both `fn` and `ln`. As an example, make it 41 as above, to accommodate a space in between.
- Also, this line `k++;` should be changed `fulln[k++] = ' ';` - that adds the space in between.

Btw, as you already include `string.h` there is no reason why you should not use the standard library `strcpy` and `strcat`. That means these two lines can replace your whole section of code:

```
strcpy(fulln, fn);
strcat(fulln, " ");
strcat(fulln, ln);
```

Comment: @SteveWhoLikesLinux there isn't any more code to write. All you need is to replace your   2 `for` loop with the above 3 lines using strcpy and strcat.